# Does anyone know how to fix this lighting problem on 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My lighting is on maximum, and I've done everything I could, even googling it. But I've found nothing to fix this problem. In the image, theres the weird blackness under slabs and stairs, like theres no lighting there. I want to find a way to get rid of that, as its never happened before.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like Hypixel to me, and if so I am not surprised. In order to cater to players that stay on 1.8 to abuse the reach/rapidhit bugs plaguing PVP, Hypixel still runs on version 1.7 which causes a lot of weird lighting glitches for players that actually update and play on the newest versions since I think they changed the lighting engine at one point.

If this is on a single player world, it is likely client side and just a visual glitch that should be solved by exiting and re-entering the world

Comment: How do you know this is Hypixel?

Comment: Because those kind of lighting glitches happen all the time there because they run on an old version.

Comment: Im a hypixel player, out of curiousity are you suggesting we use 1.7, or a newer version?

Comment: I have been told hypixel runs on 1.7 so they can conform to those noobs that stay on 1.8 so they can abuse the pvp bugs they fixed in 1.9, and none of the newer items work for some reason..

Comment: @Aceplante Hypixel's server does not run on 1.7. I know this for a fact because using a client with 1.7 hit registration is considered an unfair advantage because more of your clicks are sent to the server compared to 1.8. Also, what does it mean abuse the pvp bugs?

Comment: I have been told it runs on 1.7, and they just have anticheat to make sure your clicks per second doesnt go too high